# Satisfying Three Dimensional Coordinate Systems

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

In Multivariable Calculus, what is the best way of finding what points P(x,y,z) satisfy for example:

$$x^2 +y^2 = 4,$$ and $$z=3 $$

I've been told graphing the two equations and finding an intersection does it but is there a simpler way, algebraically maybe?

Comment: The "simplest" way is to realize that $x^2 + y^2 = 2^2$ is the equation (in 2D) of a circle of radius $2$ (_not_ disc!).  Since $z$ isn't mentioned, the "height" (if you take $z$ to be "height") can be anything thus you repeat this circle for every $z$ value, which makes a "tube"--the lateral surface of a cylinder of radius $2$ perpendicular to the $xy$-plane and centered about the $z$-axis.  Now that $z$ _is_ specified, it's the circle of radius $2$, parallel to the $xy$-plane at "height" $z = 3$.

Comment: And, fyi, this is already stated in the "algebraic" way.  If I give you a random point, you can plug in and tell me whether or not that point satisfies these two equations.

Comment: @Jared Mmmm I see, that makes a lot of sense, I was just having trouble visualizing it. Would you want to write that as an answer so I can upvote it? And thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these two equations do not share variables, you shouldn't need to solve it. The solution set is just $z=3$ and any values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2=4$. It's like asking someone to solve the equations $x=1$ and $y=2$. Generally speaking though, finding algebraic solutions is often hard unless you have a system of linear equations. You could use a [Root-Finding Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) like [Newton's Method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) in general to get a numerical solution.